# Swift: Should I Use Static Members For a Firebase Manager Class | Good Programming Design

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, object

I am making a Firebase project that requires numerous features including authentication, database, and storage. I think that making a database reference in every view controller is too strenuous, so I am making a Firebase manager class that takes care of uploading/downloading/authenticating process.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class FirebaseManager {
    var uid: String?
    var databaseRootRef: DatabaseReference?
    var storageRootRef: StorageReference?
    var authentication: Auth?

    init() {

    }

    func initialize() {
        uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        databaseRootRef = Database.database().reference()
        storageRootRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        authentication = Auth.auth()
    }

    func isAuthenticated() -> Bool {
        return authentication?.currentUser != nil
    }

    func registerUserWith(name: String, email: String, password: String, completionHandler: (@escaping (User?, Error?) -> Void)) {
    authentication?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
            completionHandler(user, error)
        })
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I am not even sure if this is good programming practice. I don't see many online tutorials do that. However, I personally think it is good because (a) My classes are created so that they have one unique purpose. My view controller doesn't need to worry about the firebase work (b) it makes a lot of my code reusable and saves a lot of lines (c) I just think that it allows me to edit any firebase related methods easier because now I only have to edit one place instead of 20 places
2. Suppose that this is good programming practice. How should I implement this class? What I am doing right now is that I create an instance in each view controller file and initialize them in each file. Alternatively, I could (a) make all the members and methods of the class static so I access them directly without initializing an object (b) don't initialize an object in each view controller but instead pass one object throughout via segue transfers. Which one is the better design method

**P.S. The reason I have a separate initialize method is that if I init the object before viewDidLoad or when I define the object, the program crashes because the Firebase references haven't been created yet.**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not using static/singleton pattern.

You can use subclassing instead.

I mean, you can create, for instance, `FirebaseViewController` which handles basic interaction with `FirebaseManager`.
The problem while using a singleton is that you can't clearly understand when your data changing.

By the way, use computed properties instead. This is the Swift-style:

```
var isAuthenticated: Bool {
        return authentication?.currentUser != nil
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for that! I kind of want to avoid using a view controller that integrates firebase methods as I want my FirebaseManager class to just be in charge of uploading/retrieving data from Firebase and not responsible for performing any action on UI elements. I agree that singleton might cause that problem. So should I create one instance and pass it around or should I initialize and create new instances in every view controller. (Like registration view controller, message chat log view controller. They all implement their UI differently and retrieve different Firebase data)

Comment: @RyanJin It's nice that you divide UI and logic. It depends on which kind of information you want to transfer between the ViewControllers.

Comment: Suppose that I am writing a message app. I have a login screen and a chat room screen (just two view controllers). Login screen authenticates the user and creates a unique user id in the firebase database while the chat room screen uses the database and the storage for chat message. I don't want to create a Database.database().reference in every class, or even in every method, so I use a FirebaseManager object to manage the data upload and download. So the only data that will be passed between the two view controllers are 1. the FirebaseManager and 2. a user id

Comment: I think that's ok. Do not forget about weak and strong references. And would suggest wrapping this class by a protocol.